# SQL query based on a range plus a row right before the first one

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to query a database based on a time range, but I would also like to add the row right before the start time.

```
time | col1 | col2
 10  |  a   |  b
 15  |  c   |  d
 23  |  e   |  f
 45  |  g   |  h
 61  |  i   |  j
 70  |  k   |  l
```

For example, if I want to query rows with time range `14` to `65` I would like the results to be

```
 10  |  a   |  b
 15  |  c   |  d
 23  |  e   |  f
 45  |  g   |  h
 61  |  i   |  j
```

As you can see, its really a regular query of time `14` (start time) to `65` (end time), plus whatever the row before `14` was.  I know there was not really a row with time `14`, but I would like this scenario to work also.

How should the SQL query look like to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(time) over (order by time) as next_time
      from t
     ) t
where next_time between 14 and 65 or
      time between 14 and 65;
```

Assuming you have at least one row in the range, you can simplify this to:

```
where next_time >= 14 and
      time <= 65
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This works.  I have a follow up question, but might be too complicated to ask in this question again, so I will ask a new question and link this answer as well

Comment: My next question is posted here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69260923/sql-query-based-on-a-range-plus-a-row-right-before-the-first-one-2).  Hopefully it makes sense